# Where is dyanmodb point in time back saved?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table and enabled Point-in-time Recovery. There is a gsi change which requires delete the table and redeploy it. I wonder whether it saves the backup if I turn it down? I'd like to recover the table from backup after redeploy. Does it work with `Point-in-time Recovery`?

Comment: When you say "turn down the table" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: it means delete the cloudformation stack which includes the table.